# Кэширование изображений в Picasso

Tags: picasso, android, java, изображения, кэширование

Использую **Picasso** для загрузки изображений в **ListView**.

Обнаружил проблему, выводит список картинок с сервера, и при обновлении списка снова их выводит, так вот, я удалил часть картинок, обновил список, выводит все, даже те что удалил (это из-за **кеширования**, наверное) перезапустил программу, не выводит, так и надо.

Вопрос, как это можно исправить? пробовал убрать **Кеширование** методом **skipMemoryCache()**,
но из-за этого, список при каждой прокрутке заново загружает изображения , так как загрузка стоит в адаптере (getView).

```
Picasso.with(ctxt).load("http://-------/NImages/"+U.getText().toString()).into(iv);
```

P.S Проблема в том, что выводит даже то, что я удалил уже на сервере, пока програму не перезапущу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам может помочь очистка кэша.

Добавьте такой класс в проект:

```
public class PicassoTools {

    public static void clearCache (Picasso p) {
        p.cache.clear();
    }
}
```

И в нужное время очищайте кэш:

```
PicassoTools.clearCache(Picasso.with(context));
```

Код взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016382/invalidate-cache-in-picasso).

При этом кэш на диске будет работать в соответствии с заголовком, когда вы получали изображение. Если там стоит no-cache или небольшое время хранения кэша, то при повторном запросе picasso не подцепит эту картинку.